# Limiting number of MAC address per port on Linux based platrform

Tags: linux, iptables, linux-networking

I'm looking to limit the number of mac addresses allowed to be learned on a specific port. Similar functionality exists on the L2 switch. For example [this](https://www.cisco.com/c/m/en_us/techdoc/dc/reference/cli/nxos/commands/l2/switchport-port-security-maximum.html#:%7E:text=To%20set%20the%20maximum%20number,no%20form%20of%20this%20command.)  cisco based configuration.
If the maximum is reached, packets with a new MAC address expected to be :

1. Not learned in Linux bridge
2. Dropped.

I would expect such a feature to be implemented in the bridge module but I did not find any related configuration/code. Is it possible to achieve the same with iptables/ebtables, any other options?

Thanks,
Ilya

Comment: The Linux bridge itself doesn't really provide anything like switch port security. Various overlays may do, such as libvirt's own bridges or Open vSwitch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*iptables* happens way too late to be useful. *ebtables* lacks too many features to be used and would anyway be subject to the same limits as *nftables*' bridge family as described below.

One possible way to do this is to use [*nftables*](https://wiki.nftables.org/wiki-nftables/index.php/Main_Page) in the *netdev* family and a [set](https://wiki.nftables.org/wiki-nftables/index.php/Sets#Named_sets_specifications) with its size set to the maximum number of allowed MAC addresses to store them, and if needed set the defaut timeout
for its elements to the bridge's ageing time.

---

### Prerequisites

The *netdev* family table requires the interface (which is a bridge port here) to exist in advance for a base chain using it to be created. So the table must be loaded only after such an interface exists. If it's a virtual interface the table should probably be loaded right after its creation, before the interface is brought up, or at least before it's set as a bridge port to prevent learning to happen.

Recent enough versions of *nftables* and the kernel should be used:

- *nftables* 0.9.1 introduced the *dynamic* keyword present below (which can still be omitted for previous versions), so *nftables* >= 0.9.1 should be preferred,
- nftables 0.8.4 introduced a new syntax to add an element from the packet path, so nftables < 0.8.4 should be avoided or the rule reworked,
- kernel 4.2 introduced support for the *netdev* family: kernel >= 4.2 is mandatory

### Implementation

If the filtering was done at the bridge level (aka *bridge family*), this would indeed filter traffic, but this would not prevent the bridge to learn any MAC address before the extra MACs are dropped by the filter, because *netfilter*'s bridge hooks are called from the bridge, after such frames were seen by the bridge (could be confirmed by running `bridge monitor fdb`). It's possible to disable learning of *all* MACs on the bridge port, but not select which are or aren't.

So this should be done *before* the bridge, to prevent it from ever seeing the MAC address so it won't have the possibility to learn it: at the interface level, using the *netdev* family. *netfilter* currently can handle only *ingress* in the *netdev* family, but that's fine because we are only interested in filtering ingress traffic for this case: traffic arriving from "outside" and entering the bridge.

As this is a relatively simple filter put before the bridge, it's not handling anything fancy. It won't handle VLAN tagged packets differently (this could probably be extended in the ruleset with additional sets and checks for specific VLANs. It's still a fixed ruleset requiring sets/chains/rules changes for most changes).

In the *netdev* family a base chain is tied to an interface.

**UPDATE**: changed the answer so it handles ageing so that a not-recently-seen MAC address slot becomes free for reuse after some time (which should better be the bridge's *ageing* time, or this time plus one second). At the same time dropped the "fast path" rule, since now each packet must update the timer for the source MAC anyway. The *update* rule behaves as an *add* rule except it also resets the timer to the timeout value (which when not stated in the *rule* is the default defined in the *set*). When a MAC address is not seen for this duration it's automatically deleted from the set by the kernel. There's only one rule left to do this:

- for any frame received, update the set with the source MAC address:

  - fail if the set is full and a new MAC address is attempted to be added, thus not execute the remaining *accept* statement,
  - else add a new MAC address in the set or refresh it if already present, with a timeout of 30s, and execute the *accept* statement
- drop anything remaining (default policy).

### Ruleset

In this example ruleset which can be loaded with `nft -f portsecmax.nft`,

- the bridge port interface is named *swp1* (it could have been *eth0* or *ens224* etc.), and the base chain was chosen with the same name,
- the size of the set used to memorize the MAC addresses is set to the maximum number of MAC addresses to allow: 3 in this example,
- the default timeout for the set's elements is chosen to be 30s which is the default *ageing_time* on a Linux bridge unless changed. If the use case is to keep forever the first *size* (here 3) seen MAC addresses, just remove `timeout 30s` below.

`portsecmax.nft`:

```
table netdev portsecmax        # for idempotency
delete table netdev portsecmax # for idempotency

table netdev portsecmax {
    set macswp1 {
        type ether_addr
        size 3
        flags dynamic,timeout
        timeout 30s
    }

    chain swp1 {
        type filter hook ingress device "swp1" priority filter; policy drop;
        update @macswp1 { ether saddr } accept comment "false if set is full and adding a new element"
    }
}
```

Resetting the list of allowed MAC addresses:

```
nft flush set netdev portsecmax macswp1
```

Disabling the feature (pick one of the three choices): remove the table or remove the chain or change the chain's default policy to *accept*:

```
nft delete table netdev portsecmax
nft delete chain netdev portsecmax swp1
nft add chain netdev portsecmax swp1 '{ policy accept; }'
```

Comment: I'd say there should also be a way if the linux bridge is replaced with an openvswitch to add custom filtering there as seen with this example: https://docs.openvswitch.org/en/latest/tutorials/ovs-advanced/#implementing-table-0-admission-control , but I don't have much experience on openvswitch or its features (are there custom mac tables available to store the first learned addresses, or the possibility to restrict the size or use the number of learned addresses in a comparison in the filter? no idea)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'm aware of the OVS option, but can't be used in my case. , nftables sounds promising, but it is not clear to me how to handle the aging process. I.e once mac is aged from Linux bridge it should be removed from this set as well.  I guess can be done using some coding, but if I need to code I think it's better to implement something using XDP.  Anyway, you gave me a real way forward will accept the answer.

Comment: Ideally, I don't want to know about the mac address itself I'm caring about count only.  At configuration time I have no idea about which MAC will enter my system I only know that I need to limit the number of MACs.  So If I allowed 3 mac per port and the table is less than 3 traffic should pass if the number is 3 I need to pass only one that matches the learned mac.

Comment: I updated the answer.